# In Java code, how to properly handle scala future in format of Future[Try[Option[Map[String, Any]]]]

Tags: java, scala, future

I need to call scala API in java code. The scala API looks like:
`def get(id: String): Future[Try[Option[Map[String, Any]]]]`

In java code, how to handle the Future[Try[Option]] properly and get Map if everything is a success? If there is an exception, or Future is a failure, then re-throw RuntimeException.

Comment: `Future[Try[_]]` rarely makes sense

Comment: You can use https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat to convert scala futures to Java futures,

Comment: @cchantep It makes sense if you want to call a function that returns `Try` asynchronously and track whether the `Future` failed or succeeded.

Comment: I hardly does. Stacking such validation types just lead to overcomplex API. Just convert `Try` to `Future` and `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

> `Future[Try[Option[Map[String, Any]]]]`

Is an overkill, because result of evaluation of a future already looks like a try. So, let you have such a future, then simplest way - is to use Await.result and then cut through types stack:

```
Future<Try<Option<Map<String, Any>>>> yourFuture = yourFunc(...);
scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration timeout = new FiniteDuration(..., ...);
/*simplest, but not the best way of doing so, it will throw an exception if something goes wrong, you probably want to wrap this in try-catch block in real code*/

Try<Option<Map<String, Any>>> result = Await.result<Try<Option<Map<String, Any>>>>(yourFuture, timeout);

if(result.isSuccess()){
  Option<Map<String, Any>> option = result();
  if(option.nonEmpty()){
    Map<String, Any> mapYouNeed = option.get(); 
  } else {
  //  throw your exception
  }
} else {
  //  throw your exception
}
```

More info on Futures and Await in scala docs.
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/concurrent/Await$.html